# Examples of time-varying graph-structured data in real world

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, datasets, geometric-deep-learning

I'm looking for examples of time-varying graph-structured data for time-varying graph CNNs. First, I came up with the idea of infection network. Is there anything more? If possible, I want data that can be easily obtained online.

Comment: So, you're looking for applications and related datasets?

Comment: @nbro yes, do  you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at traffic data for example if you follow 
[link1](https://github.com/liyaguang/DCRNN), [link2](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tkwon/TMCdata/TMCarchive.html) you can find 3 publicly available traffic datasets which are already preprocessed. You cold also look at air quality datasets offered by the government [link3](https://aqs.epa.gov/aqsweb/airdata/download_files.html#Meta)